# Multidimensional array for schedule app

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to create and populate an Array with the following:

An array represents a day, that has 42 time slots, from 7:30 to 18:00.

An array item corresponding to such a slot, must contain the Client Name, the slot start, the slot end, a Vehicle that the Client can use and a flag for if to display the array record.

I have 14 persons, and the above array should be repeated for each of them in a top-level array (of 14 day-arrays).

So the first level array represents persons 1 to 14. The second level array represents time slots 1 - 42. The third level array represents the data (Client, Vehicle,... etc).

I have the following code:

```
$slots = array(
    "1" =>
        array(
            "1" => 0, array("ClientName" => "", "Start" => 0, "End" => 0, "VehicleRegistration" => ""),
            "2" => 0, array("ClientName" => "", "Start" => 0, "End" => 0, "VehicleRegistration" => ""),
            "3" => 0, array("ClientName" => "", "Start" => 0, "End" => 0, "VehicleRegistration" => ""),
// ...
            "42" => 0, array("ClientName" => "", "Start" => 0, "End" => 0, "VehicleRegistration" => ""),
        ),
    "2" =>
        array(
            "1" => 0, array("ClientName" => "", "Start" => 0, "End" => 0, "VehicleRegistration" => ""),
            "2" => 0, array("ClientName" => "", "Start" => 0, "End" => 0, "VehicleRegistration" => ""),
            "3" => 0, array("ClientName" => "", "Start" => 0, "End" => 0, "VehicleRegistration" => ""),
// ...
            "42" => 0, array("ClientName" => "", "Start" => 0, "End" => 0, "VehicleRegistration" => ""),
        ),
    "14" =>
        array(
            "1" => 0, array("ClientName" => "", "Start" => 0, "End" => 0, "VehicleRegistration" => ""),
            "2" => 0, array("ClientName" => "", "Start" => 0, "End" => 0, "VehicleRegistration" => ""),
            "3" => 0, array("ClientName" => "", "Start" => 0, "End" => 0, "VehicleRegistration" => ""),
// ...
            "42" => 0, array("ClientName" => "", "Start" => 0, "End" => 0, "VehicleRegistration" => ""),
        ),
);
```

But the population results in an array where I have mostly 0 values and hardly any data (Client, ...). It seems like most information is lost.

How should I create this nested array correctly?

Comment: first number is person 1- 14 as there are 14 people who it will cover

Comment: 2nd number is time slot 1 - 42

Comment: sorry english is not my first language lol - the date doesn't matter as thats covered in SQL.   The flag and the placing of the ( ) I need an array of [1][1][1] if that makes sense

Comment: flag at end of each array.                                                                           ie person  (timeslotstart, (timeslotend, vehicle)), showflag

Answer (score 0):

Your day-array definition overwrites itself because you have a mix of specific numerical key/value pairs and non-keyed arrays:

```
"1"=>0, array("ClientName"=>"", "Start"=>0, "End"=>0, "VehicleRegistration"=>""),
```

The above line represents two elements. I split the line to highlight this fact:

```
"1"=>0,
array("ClientName"=>"", "Start"=>0, "End"=>0, "VehicleRegistration"=>""),
```

The first element is put in the specified index, i.e. at index "1". The second element is added to the next available index, i.e. 2, but then in the next line you re-assign 0 to that same index:

```
"2" => 0,
```

So the array you assigned to index 2 (with ClientName, etc) is overwritten by the value 0.

And so it continues; you keep overwriting the previous array with the value 0.

What you really want is to move that 0-value inside the array that follows it, and name it (e.g. "Flag"), like this:

```
array("Flag"=>0, "ClientName"=>"", "Start"=>0, "End"=>0, "VehicleRegistration"=>""),
```

#### Code to generate the array

Here is code to generate an array with 42 slots for one day, multiplied for 14 persons, so you don't have to literally type all of it:

```
function createPersonsDay($slots, $persons) {
    return array_fill_keys(
        range(1, $persons), // number of persons
        array_fill_keys(
            range(1, $slots), // number of slots
            array(
                "Flag" => false,
                "ClientName" => "",
                "Start" => 0,
                "End" => 0,
                "VehicleRegistration" => ""
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Call it like this:

```
$personsDay = createPersonsDay(42, 14);
```

Now *$personsDay* is:

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    1 => 
    array (
      'Flag' => false,
      'ClientName' => '',
      'Start' => 0,
      'End' => 0,
      'VehicleRegistration' => '',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'Flag' => false,
      'ClientName' => '',
      'Start' => 0,
      'End' => 0,
      'VehicleRegistration' => '',
    ),
    ...
    42 => 
    array (
      'Flag' => false,
      'ClientName' => '',
      'Start' => 0,
      'End' => 0,
      'VehicleRegistration' => '',
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    1 => 
    array (
      'Flag' => false,
      'ClientName' => '',
      'Start' => 0,
      'End' => 0,
      'VehicleRegistration' => '',
    ),
    ...

  14 => 
  array (
    1 => 
    array (
      'Flag' => false,
      'ClientName' => '',
      'Start' => 0,
      'End' => 0,
      'VehicleRegistration' => '',
    ),
    ...
    42 => 
    array (
      'Flag' => false,
      'ClientName' => '',
      'Start' => 0,
      'End' => 0,
      'VehicleRegistration' => '',
    ),
  ),
)
```

The inner associative array has a property "Flag", which seemed more appropriate than the mix of a key (with numerical value, the flag), and a non-named array, as it appears in your question.

Comment: Thank you so very much - I see where I was going wrong now, your multiple brackets at the ending           I thought it was     $slot => array ( array [1] ==>"all of the keys") )